# Select2 working incorrectly with Formsets

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, jquery-select2

I have script like this and this working with only first form, others are frozen and did not work at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_membership-0-company').select2();
});
```

I'm not able to change # to . because of every new form have new id like `id_membership-0-company`, `id_membership-1-company` and so on, and all my forms have same class (this field don't have separate class)

I'm not able to just add all id's inside this function because of it works only when the page is loaded so only id 0 will work this way

I was try to do something like this: add `onclick="addRow()"` inside "Add form" button html tag and this code in script. Without Timeout function it doesn't work because script executes too fast.
It works for two forms (if I press "Add form" button) but not working if I adding more id's (in this scenario after the second form many more incorrect forms created for this field)

```
function addRow() {
    function activateForms(){
        $('#id_membership-0-company').select2();
        $('#id_membership-1-company').select2();
        }
        setTimeout(activateForms, 1000);
    }
```

How to fix that? I need select2 widget for first field of every form?

Comment: Instead you can use simple  `$('select').select2();`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, I tried this and only the first form works with this code

Comment: Can you show us what happens when you click Add Form. (Does this trigger an ajax call etc) so i can best format your answer

Comment: If I do so: 
`$(document).ready(function() {
 $('select').select2();
});`
Only first form will work, others just frozen and Im not able to select something.

If I create timeouts or trigger function after button Add Form added its behaves strangely & create many excess forms some are working and some are frozen

Answer (score 1):

I create a small example for you, so you can adapt to your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2();
});

$('.addSelect').on('click', function() {
  const arr = [{
      val: 1,
      text: 'One'
    },
    {
      val: 2,
      text: 'Two'
    },
    {
      val: 3,
      text: 'Three'
    }
  ];

  const sel = $('<select>').appendTo('.container');
  $(arr).each(function() {
    sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
  });  
  $(sel).select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <select>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button class='addSelect'>Add Select2</button>
```

Comment: Do I able to pass objects to `const arr` because my `<select>` & `<option>` tags are generated automatically?

Comment: That's just an example you can just add `$('select').select2();` after you append select to your page with your script.

Comment: I append my forms with django formset, so if I trigger the `$('select').select2();` every time I add the form there are many forms generated some of them are working some not

Comment: You can use `sel` like my update example.

Comment: if I create just `$('select').select2();` first form activated, but others are chaotic, some of them are working as select2, and some of them freeze, some just without select2
I find out that if I activate forms with `$('select').select2();` after I added all forms it works, but I dont know how to put it to work for every separate form

Comment: We need to see how you create form so.